# Python and Finance Timeseries Mystery Numbers

Tags: python, time, finance

I have a collection of data from a website called Stooq.com, I'm using it to back test trading strategies on 5min candles, the data downloaded gives columns of

```
<TICKER>,<PER>,<DATE>,<TIME>,<OPEN>,<HIGH>,<LOW>,<CLOSE>,<VOL>,<OPENINT>
```

This is all fine and dandy except I have no idea what the time column is formatted as. Here is an example daily cycle

```
<TICKER>,<PER>,<DATE>,<TIME>,<OPEN>,<HIGH>,<LOW>,<CLOSE>,<VOL>,<OPENINT>
SPY.US,5,20210702,153000,431.67,431.79,431.37,431.51,1309413,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,153500,431.52,431.69,431.48,431.6,642159,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,154000,431.6,431.63,431.33,431.56,832221,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,154500,431.56,431.895,431.55,431.88,797430,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,155000,431.875,431.92,431.747,431.865,509106,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,155500,431.86,431.9,431.76,431.81,419615,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,160000,431.815,431.89,431.695,431.815,425193,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,160500,431.815,431.89,431.74,431.83,419253,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,161000,431.82,431.825,431.61,431.68,455377,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,161500,431.68,431.93,431.68,431.885,490799,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,162000,431.885,431.93,431.78,431.855,307473,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,162500,431.863,431.97,431.79,431.88,357098,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,163000,431.88,431.93,431.78,431.865,433461,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,163500,431.865,431.925,431.75,431.91,294982,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,164000,431.91,431.94,431.74,431.782,359206,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,164500,431.79,431.858,431.74,431.845,249240,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,165000,431.85,431.94,431.76,431.915,256071,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,165500,431.91,431.959,431.858,431.9,254839,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,170000,431.89,431.96,431.855,431.9,285437,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,170500,431.9,431.955,431.84,431.905,208983,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,171000,431.9,432.1,431.89,431.94,400942,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,171500,431.935,432.02,431.92,431.985,160252,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,172000,431.99,432.03,431.9,432.02,182315,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,172500,432.01,432.13,431.92,432.12,284309,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,173000,432.11,432.12,432.04,432.1,315266,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,173500,432.1,432.17,432.04,432.148,388027,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,174000,432.15,432.175,432.06,432.16,339045,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,174500,432.15,432.3,432.15,432.3,485802,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,175000,432.295,432.41,432.29,432.4,279838,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,175500,432.395,432.65,432.395,432.45,716681,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,180000,432.45,432.51,432.41,432.44,219580,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,180500,432.45,432.48,432.43,432.44,156405,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,181000,432.43,432.46,432.34,432.37,203111,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,181500,432.375,432.5,432.34,432.48,176611,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,182000,432.485,432.525,432.44,432.445,174365,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,182500,432.445,432.55,432.445,432.5,151706,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,183000,432.49,432.725,432.46,432.71,366646,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,183500,432.709,432.83,432.68,432.81,315928,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,184000,432.818,432.975,432.78,432.975,349203,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,184500,432.975,433.093,432.94,433.07,451322,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,185000,433.07,433.245,433.03,433.21,498166,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,185500,433.208,433.3,433.16,433.27,324046,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,190000,433.26,433.48,433.26,433.455,447354,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,190500,433.455,433.49,433.17,433.195,579655,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,191000,433.198,433.23,433.12,433.19,449242,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,191500,433.2,433.24,433.06,433.07,398212,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,192000,433.06,433.2,433.06,433.17,378096,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,192500,433.18,433.219,433.12,433.16,256487,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,193000,433.16,433.22,433.03,433.055,239991,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,193500,433.06,433.23,433.055,433.228,209481,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,194000,433.22,433.39,433.22,433.37,415339,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,194500,433.375,433.375,433.221,433.355,290726,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,195000,433.36,433.36,433.2,433.222,223218,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,195500,433.23,433.338,433.229,433.31,229061,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,200000,433.312,433.38,433.27,433.35,278286,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,200500,433.342,433.465,433.34,433.435,395446,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,201000,433.432,433.48,433.36,433.39,228603,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,201500,433.395,433.45,433.35,433.43,174415,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,202000,433.44,433.54,433.421,433.515,293634,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,202500,433.52,433.56,433.46,433.556,260106,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,203000,433.56,433.56,433.43,433.5,239319,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,203500,433.49,433.57,433.435,433.45,330890,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,204000,433.46,433.49,433.32,433.38,407721,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,204500,433.38,433.395,433.22,433.285,380243,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,205000,433.29,433.305,433.19,433.21,260335,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,205500,433.22,433.315,433.18,433.267,274666,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,210000,433.26,433.39,433.19,433.37,426448,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,210500,433.38,433.6,433.38,433.56,755376,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,211000,433.56,433.67,433.42,433.5,615957,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,211500,433.5,433.615,433.5,433.58,329449,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,212000,433.58,433.62,433.5,433.57,640957,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,212500,433.56,433.64,433.54,433.6,521215,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,213000,433.605,433.67,433.55,433.56,524997,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,213500,433.56,433.73,433.44,433.7,1099109,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,214000,433.695,433.76,433.61,433.71,1228773,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,214500,433.71,433.83,433.66,433.78,1510092,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,215000,433.781,434.1,433.78,433.96,3160681,0
SPY.US,5,20210702,215500,433.97,434,433.53,433.72,5860685,0
```

The time column starts the day at 153000 and ends at 215500, it goes up in increments of 500, which makes some sense, 500=5mins, so you would assume 1000=10mins and so on, but then numbers increment the 10000s when the 1000s hits 6000, which maybe for 60min is an hours so increment, none of it makes any sense from what I can see and as far as I'm aware have no correlation to epoch time, hours, mins, or seconds from a certain time, and are just quite frankly almost useless. Someone with a financial background might know something about this but time data is pretty common in python anyway so maybe someone else knows. Any clue as to what these numbers would mean helps.

what I'm looking for is to convert them to a time series object and then have some formatting of hour:minute

Comment: Isn't the format just `HHMM00`?

Comment: `HHMMSS` would make sense given a similar date format of `YYMMDD`

Comment: @Mark this, considering that with these increments the seconds will always be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me that "153000" is in fact "15:30:00" = 3 pm 30 minutes 0 seconds (HHMMSS). This is consistent with the fact that the 3rd number never goes above 5.

Assuming the type is string you can convert it to total second:

```
t='153000'
int(t[:2])*3600+int(t[2:4])*60+int(t[4:])
```

Output: `55800`

Of course the best remains to use specialized modules, such as pandas, to read this data as DataFrame and handle this conversion automatically.

Comment: Yeah this turns out to be correct, funnily enough the reason why it makes since since it's stock data is because this website Stooq where I got the data is polish, 3:30pm Poland time is 9:30am new york when the markets open.